# Children is overflowing parent when using tailwind and aspect ratio

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I have tried some solutions but none of them are working and keep overflowing the parent container after the screen size excees certain size. The expected behavior should be that the item shrinks to keep the aspect ratio. I have used flex and flex shrink but it isnt getting smaller to fit the container. I am kinda noobie. I have tried flex, shrink, setting a maximun width(this one works but its like just hides the rest of the component so it keeps acting like it overflows and makes the page scrollable)

[How it looks on a small screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqcQA.png)

[How it looks on a large screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBjVx.png)

[How it looks on a medium screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8pur.png)

Component code

```typescript
"use client"

import { cn } from '@/lib/utils';
import { AspectRatio } from '@/components/ui/aspect-ratio';
import * as React from 'react'

interface GridViewProps {
    children?: React.ReactNode;
    className?: string;
    pageType?: 'A4';
}

const GridView: React.FC<GridViewProps> = ({children, className, pageType = 'A4'}) => {

    let ratio;

    switch (pageType) {
        case 'A4': 
            ratio = 210 / 297
        // Here you can add more page types, also remember to add them to the interface
            
    }

    return (
                <AspectRatio className={cn("relative p-10 bg-slate-400 max-h-xs w-auto", className)} ratio={21/29.7}>
                    <div className=''>
                        {children}
                    </div>
                </AspectRatio>
            
    );
}

export {GridView}
```

`page.tsx` code:

```typescript
import { GridView } from '@/components/ui/gridview'
import { Card, CardContent, CardDescription, CardTitle } from '@/components/ui/card'
import { Separator } from '@/components/ui/separator'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className="flex flex-col md:flex-row flex-auto h-screen p-5 gap-3 items-stretch">

        <Card className='grow-[2] p-5 flex flex-col'>
          <CardTitle>Stickers to Grid</CardTitle>
          <CardDescription className='invisible md:visible'>Drop here the items you want to add to your sticker grid!</CardDescription>
          <Separator className="my-4 invisible md:visible"></Separator>
          

          <GridView className='' pageType='A4'></GridView>
          
        
        </Card>


        <Card className='flex-grow p-6 flex flex-col invisible md:visible sm:invisible'>
          <CardTitle>Pick your stickers</CardTitle>
          <CardDescription className='invisible md:visible'>Drag here the items you want to add to your sticker grid!</CardDescription>
          <Separator className="my-4 invisible md:visible"></Separator>
        </Card>
    </main>
  )
}
```